# OpenGL: Crashes at random OpenGL function call

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, opengl

I am getting weird problem, the crash happens at random times, for example i managed to use the 3d app for a while without crashing, then most of the times it crashes always when i suddenly render a lot of objects at same time.

I have recently noticed that changing the huge texture surface on this ATI card will crash my whole computer when using huge texture sizes and a lot of them and switching from one to another in one frame. So it is a possibility i have broken ATI card or just buggy one. But it is imporobable since i've added some code lately and now i have noticed this crash first time. I didnt use any special opengl calls, just the good old glbegin() glend() glcolor() etc...

If i comment out the line where it crashed previously, for example glBegin(GL_QUADS) ... glEnd() Then next time i get crash on different openGL function call at different place of my code, for example glColor4f() and then i comment that out, and the next crash i get at glClear() at totally different part of the rendering code!

What could be causing these? Im using ATI card, and i am aware some opengl calls may crash the program if they are using improper values, like glLineWidth(4) will crash some ATI cards on a random line of openGL code because the max line width is 3!

Edit:

When i run the program in debug mode with ApplicationVerifier, it throws me this line:

```
if(!(PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd))){
```

I dont understand, what could possibly be wrong on it?

pfd:

```
static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
   // *correct amount of elements*
};
```

Comment: The best thing to do is to try your program on a computer with another GPU and see if it also crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, chances are pretty good that the crash in OpenGL is only a symptom, and the real problem lies elsewhere. In general, your description sounds more or less typical for resource misuse (e.g., memory leakage, using a dangling pointer, trashing the heap, etc.)

Something like a driver bug is certainly *possible* -- in fact a graphics driver is big and complex enough that *some* bugs are probably almost inevitable. The obvious test for that would be to run *other* code that uses OpenGL and see if it works dependably. It's always possible that you're using an execution path that contains a bug, but is so obscure almost nothing else uses it so the bug isn't otherwise triggered -- but given that the crash isn't happening in a fixed location, that seems fairly unlikely (still possible, just unlikely). If a graphics driver has a bug (especially one serious enough to cause crashes, not just mis-rendering), it usually becomes known pretty quickly.

Comment: Seems like you are right... i slipped through the big textures in the debug folder >_> no longer crashes! But still doesnt help with the application verifier tool error line, i have no idea whats that about :7

Answer (score 0):

Such random behaviour is usually the symptom of a stack/heap corruption. You should check that you're not corrupting the heap and/or the stack. Buggy drivers is also a option, since crashing on a invalid value is a bug, that should not crash and instead produce a GL error.

Comment: That desnt support windows >_>